# Error of copying data from one workbook to current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy data from one workbook to another workbook but it shows mw error 1004. Could someone help me to check? I set my another workbook as x and my current workbook as wb.

```
Sub foo()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim PFilepath As String
Dim PFile As String
Dim Period As String

PFilepath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4")
PFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5")
Period = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")
PPeriod = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2")
'lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Accidental Claims List"
Worksheets("Accidental Claims List").Tab.ColorIndex = 39
Worksheets.Add().Name = Period & " Accidental Claims"
Worksheets(Period & " Accidental Claims").Tab.ColorIndex = 39
Worksheets.Add().Name = "DTH&TPD Claims List"
Worksheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Tab.ColorIndex = 33
Worksheets.Add().Name = Period & " DTH&TPD"
Worksheets(Period & " DTH&TPD").Tab.ColorIndex = 33

Workbooks.Open (PFilepath & PFile)
Set x = Workbooks.Open(PFilepath & PFile)

x.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Range("A1:W9999").Copy
wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Range("A1:W9999").PasteSpecial.Text



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi is `I4` empty ?

Comment: Nope I4 &I5 contain file path and it is available. The errors pop out when I insert copy and paste formula

Comment: yiehan it seems that the path you put in `I4` is false, can you check if your computer can access to the path

Comment: The computer can access the file. The errors come in when I insert copy and paste part.

Answer (score 0):

`Range.PasteSpecial` doesn't have a method `.Text`. Instead, try

```
wb.Sheets("DTH&TPD Claims List").Range("A1:W9999").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Note that there is no dot between `PasteSpecial` and `xlPasteValues`. `PasteSpecial` has no methods.
`xlPasteValues` is the value for the parameter `Paste` (of type `xlPasteType`) that forces `PasteSpecial` to copy only values. 
Furthermore, you open the workbook `PFilepath & PFile` twice - you can delete the first `Open`-statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The errors are at the first row of addsheet(). It is no problem without inserting copy and paste part but the error comes when I inserted copy and paste part.

Comment: You should add that information to your question, together with the error text (there are different causes for a 1004). Maybe you have a problem with naming the worksheet `"Accidental Claims List"` because there is already such a sheet (e.g. from the last run of your routine)?